# Extract list of Sources (branches) from Bitbucket using Python

Tags: python, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I'm new to python and trying to update someone else's code.

I need to pull a list of Sources (branches) from Bitbucket to allow user selection from that list. The existing code successfully used *URL* requests to retrieve lists from Bitbucket for both Projects and Repositories but I can't find a way to access the Source location to change from the default "Master" to a user selected branch.  For reference, this excerpt of code worked to extract the Repositories information:

```
@app.route("/initial3" , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def initial3():
    selected_git_project = str(request.form.get('git_project'))
    selected_git_repository = str(request.form.get('git_information'))
    #checkbox_all_selection = str(request.form.get('checkbox_all'))
    confluence_information = [str(request.form.get('confluence_information'))]
    selected_page = request.form.get('page_id')
    returnlistsearch = []
    url = 'https://git.ourcompanyname.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/'+selected_git_project+'/repos/'+selected_git_repository+'/files?limit=1000'
    resources_json = requests.get(url, auth=(git_user, git_password)).json()
    resources_json_dump = (json.dumps(resources_json, indent=4, sort_keys=False))
    decoded = json.loads(resources_json_dump)
    for x in decoded['values']:
        if '.robot' in x:
            location=os.path.dirname(x)
            if location!='':
                returnlistsearch.append(location)
    returnlistsearch =remove_duplicated(returnlistsearch)
    return render_template('initial3.html',git_repository=selected_git_repository,git_project=selected_git_project ,git_information=returnlistsearch)
```

I thought I could reuse the same code but with a modified URL (some references on docs.atlassian seemed to indicate that would work):

```
url = 'https://git.ourcompanyname.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/'+selected_git_project+'/repos/'+selected_git_repository+'/files?limit=1000'
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated - My first look EVER at python was two days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After significant trial and error I've discovered the syntax that works.  The branch reference is applied at the end of the HTTP request.

Retrieve the branch information:

```
url = 'https://git.ourcompanyname.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/'+project+'/repos/'+repository+'/files?limit=10000&at='+branch
```

Retrieve the list of files within the branch:

```
url2 = 'https://git.ourcompanyname.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/'+project+'/repos/'+repository+'/browse/' + results + '?at='+branch
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to do it through http requests, I would recommend using GitPython library. You can use it to access any repository.

[Here is the tutorial, how to use it.](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)

Comment: I really need to just build on the existing code which does rely on the http requests.

Comment: If you don't want to use GitPython library. You can check out how it's built and mimic the approach. `https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython`  or explore Bitbucket API. Hopefully someone else will have a more specific answer.